# Python: Evaluate Arithmetic String Within Pandas Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To preface this, I'm a python newbie.  I'm working on a script to automate a reporting process for website downtime each month.  I've successfully built a script that scrapes our monitoring site with Beautifulsoup and pulls the data into a pandas dataframe.  The "Duration" column of the dataframe lists downtime and comes in as "6 Minutes" or "1 Hour 5 Minutes" when scraped.  I've been able to strip the " Minutes" from the values < 1 hour and am able to convert that to an integer to operate math on.

The values greater than 1 Hour are giving me issues.  I first stripped the " Minutes" string from the end which leaves me with "1 Hour 5":

```py
df["Duration"] = df["Duration"].str.replace(" Minutes", "")
```

I then tried to switch the " Hour " into a math expression and hoped that it would by default just give me "65" but it's simply giving me the string "1*60+5" when I try to export the dataframe to an excel sheet.

```py
df["Duration"] = df["Duration"].str.replace(" Hour ", "*60+")
```

Is there any way I can parse through the "Duration" column, find any values that have "Hour" in them, and convert it into a math expression that automatically outputs the value in a "Minutes" sum?

SAMPLE DATA:

[Sampledata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQqT8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Updated answer to reflect new information.)

```
# Sample data:
ddict = {
    'Record': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Duration': ['1 Hour 5 Minutes',
                 '2 Hours 1 Minute',
                 '2 Hours 45 Minutes',
                 '7 Minutes']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(ddict)


### Replace plurals in 'Duration' using regular expression option in pandas.Series.replace()
df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].replace(r'Hours', 'Hour', regex=True).replace(r'Minutes', 'Minute', regex=True)

### Iterate the dataframe index; Check if 'Hour' in 'Duration' value for each row; Calculate total time
for i in df.index:
    if 'Hour' in df['Duration'][i]:
        df.loc[i, 'Duration'] = (int(df['Duration'][i].split('Hour')[0].strip()) * 60) + int(df['Duration'][i].split('Hour')[1].replace('Minute', '').strip())
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'Duration'] = int(df['Duration'][i].split('Minute')[0].strip())
```

Output:

```
   Record  Duration
0       1        65
1       2       121
2       3       165
3       4         7
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added what my data looks like to the end of the original post (not sure how to do it in a comment).   I ran the Lambda function and it threw the following error (not sure if it's due to the fact that some rows do not have 'Hour' in them): "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7 Minutes'"

Comment: Okay, I updated it.  I assume that Duration won't have 'Hours' without 'Minutes'. You could probably take the answer and improve it once you see what's going on. Thanks for the screenshot!